# addToBackStack exits app

Tags: android, fragment

I call addToBackStack before committing a 'replace' transaction. My understanding is that hitting android's built in 'back' button should cause the transaction to reverse, reverting focus to the original fragment, but instead the app closes. This isn't a crash; my log reveals no errors. My thought is that the backstack is empty, and that this is the default behavior for hitting 'back' on an empty backstack, but the backstack *shouldn't* be empty. I'm pretty new to this, so I'm wondering if I'm not implementing something I should have.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] names = new String[] {"Stephen Fry", "Bertrand Russell", "Hugh Laurie", "Angela Merkel"};
    final String[] descriptions = new String[] {"Comedian, actor, quizmaster, and all around goodie",
                                            "Mathematician, philosopher, maker of sacreligious kettles",
                                            "Comedian, pianist, and fake TV doctor",
                                            "German chancellor, EU ringleader, and bad haircut haver"};


    final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    final TextFragment descriptionsFragment = (TextFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.descriptions_fragment);
    final TextView descriptionsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptions_view);

    ListAdapter namesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

    final ListFragment namesFragment = new ListFragment(){
        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, descriptionsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            descriptionsView.setText(descriptions[position]);

        }
    };
    namesFragment.setListAdapter(namesAdapter);

    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, namesFragment).commit();




}
```

And the activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.twofragmentsthree.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<fragment android:name="com.example.twofragmentsthree.TextFragment"
    android:id="@+id/descriptions_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptions_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</fragment>
```

Comment: Is your fragment specified explicitly by class name in layout file? Why dont you instantiate new descriptionfragment instead of getting it from layout file?

Comment: I just posted the layout file. The fragment is specified by class name in the layout file. I got the fragment from the layout file largely because I'm not very comfortable with adding views to fragments programmatically yet. I'm now writing a version that does this programmatically, but I'm wondering why addToBackStack would work for one version rather than the other?